# Assistance for PDF to PDF/A Conversion Supporting Multiple Standards (1A, 1B, 2A, 2B, 2U, 3A, 3B, 3U)

Tags: javascript, python, php, pdf, pdfa

I am currently working on a project that requires the conversion of PDF files to PDF/A format, specifically adhering to various standards such as 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B, 2U, 3A, 3B, 3U. I have explored several libraries and tools in Python, Node.js, PHP, and JavaScript, but have encountered limitations in achieving the desired results.

**Libraries Tried:**

**PHP:**
TCPDF,
Mpdf

**Node.js:**
pdf-lib

**Python:**
reportlab,
Ghostscript (Limited to 1B, 2B, 3B standards),
ironpdf

Unfortunately, none of the above solutions have provided the comprehensive conversion support I am seeking. I would greatly appreciate any recommendations or guidance on libraries or tools that can successfully convert PDFs to all the mentioned standards (1A, 1B, 2A, 2B, 2U, 3A, 3B, 3U).

I am open to switching between programming languages (Python, Node.js, PHP, JavaScript) and would be grateful for any insights or suggestions from the community.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!